# Run a script from root and it calls another script that was in the sudo oracle. how to do that without asking the password of the oracle

Tags: linux, database, oracle, shell, unix

I'm logging into a linux machine with root and after login i have used su - oracle to connect my database. Now I've 2 shell scripts one at root home and one at home/oracle. In the home/oracle I've wrote a script for taking the backup of the database. The script available in the root is nohup ssh oracle@onprem-svcdb /home/oracle/test.sh while running the script its asking the password of the oracle, I don't need it to be like this while running the scripts It doesn't need to ask the password and it needs to run the script in oracle. What I need to do for that??? Can anyone help for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try expect tool:

You will start expect script below, that will start your main sql-script in return and will send **oracle** password if prompted:

```
content of /tmp/expect.exp script:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# set Variables
set password '***'
set timeout -1

# what to execute
spawn /usr/bin/su oracle -c "/tmp/main_script.sh"
match_max 100000

# Look for passwod prompt
while {1 > 0 } {
expect "*?assword:*"

# Send password aka $password
send -- "$password\r"
}

# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```

than your main script will be stored in (or root home, whatever dir you need):

```
/tmp/main_script.sh content:
su - oracle
drop table; create table; other SQL commands
```

One disadvantage is - plain text password, stored inside the script

How to install: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/execute-commands-on-multiple-hosts-using-expect-tool-part-iii.html

Or you could try to modify visudo , like :

```
user1    ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
```

where : user1 will be granted  "su to user2" without password prompt. You can replace also /bin/bash by ALL and then you could launch any command as user2

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replies the issue I got is fixed ... I take the rsa key of root from .sshkey and paste the same it in the .ssh key file in the oracle and it starts to work and its not asking the password now....

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replies the issue I got is fixed ... 

I take the key from id_rsa.pub from .ssh folder and paste the same copied key and paste it in the .authorized_keys file in the oracle .ssh folder

After that it starts to work and its not asking the password now....

Thanks for your valuable replies

Answer (score 1):

If I understand corrently, you are getting a password prompt on using a script which connects to your database and executes something. If you dont need a password prompt , you would need to generate public and private keys for ssh for the logged in user , in your linux machine and get it configured in the database. Please have a look at the below link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/sshuser-33/index.html

---

You can try the below

```
Let this be you env variables.
---------VARIABLES --------------
export APP_USER=something
export APP_PASS=somepass
export APP_SID=sid


Here is the script with a execute permission.

--------------SCRIPT TO RUN SQL----------
#!/usr/ksh
sqlplus << END_OF_SQL
$APP_USER/$APP_PASS@APP_SID

select * from dual;
END_OF_SQL
exit $?
----------END SCRIPT----------
```

Source : https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:142212348066

Comment: Actually my question is with different machines we can able to do it through ssh and it can be done through key generation but in my case its not like that. Within the same machine I login through root and its password and then for going into oracle directory i'm using su - oracle in that time its not asking password for me. but I have a script at home/oracle directory that needs to be run in root folder itself with some script or something but I dont need to provide the password... Can you get me...?